How can I filter a range of cells in one column and return data from another?
I am scraping data from a site and pulling data from this dump to another sheet.  The dump creates files with 2 columns, one with a date and timestamp in 15 minute intervals, and the second column is the data I need returned (number).  I get 3 days worth of data and only need a 24hr span.
How can I create a range based on cell data?  What I need to do is pull a specific range based on cell data and return the data in the next column.  Thanks

Could you show the formulae you have tried so far, and a representation of the table, in the question?

Thanks for the reply, idk where to begin to write a formula, I've just been pointing and selecting the range manually.  There are 2 columns, column A is date (dd-month-yy xx:xx pm CDT) and column B is a number value.   I need to pull and 24 time range (which is different cell numbers across multiple sheets) and return the column B value into another sheet.  Thanks

It's best to share us with a simple sample for better understanding,

If you're using Excel 365 then the FILTER function should help.
